# hta run exe from text

Tags: exe, hta

I'm looking for a code to launch exe's stored in a sub folder of an hta. It must work for 97 exe's. I've tried multiple codes with no luck.
I would like the link to be text but I could live with buttons.

Comment: You could use `WScript.Shell` and commandline: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

use "Wscript.shell"

I write my hta's in javascript; where the code is like:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");  
shell.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn]);
```

as documented at:
http://ss64.com/vb/run.html